# What is the difference between SAM and SLAM?

Tags: slam

What is the difference between *Smoothing and Mapping* (SAM) and *Simultaneous Localization and Mapping* (SLAM)? These general approaches seem closely related. Can someone describe the differences?

Answer (score 8):

SLAM is the process of locating oneself in a totally unknown environment where you are simultaneously mapping your environment and plotting your position in that environment. SAM is a technique used in SLAM to help keep the map constant by correlating current data with past data to normalize sensor error, It is simply one of many techniques for this purpose.